# How does Dreamhost Restrict User Accounts?

Tags: security, hosting, users, dreamhost

Browsing around my shared hosting account on Dreamhost, I noticed that I could not create users if the name is already taken. I can cd /home/username if I created the username, but I can't cd /home/username if the username is not one I created. I can't even begin to explain what is going on with the enhanced security box enabled.

Can anyone possibly explain what Dreamhost does to get this level of security?

Thanks!

Comment: That's pretty basic Linux security...

Comment: You are more than welcomed to answer the question then. :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Comment: Really? All they use is chmod? I'm aware of its existence but by no means am I familiar with it. I suppose now is the best time to learn it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, all the users you create are in the same group. Every other user is in a different group then you.  With some trivial filesystem permissions, you would get exactly the behavior indicated.  I'm actually rather surprised they let you create users in the first place.